# Симуляция планеты

Tags: python, циклы

Мне нужна помощь с этим кодом
После выполнения кода и значения c=100 мне нужно чтобы рост популяции цианобактерий остановился.

```
import time
import random
from random import randint
import sys
cyanobacter= 0
trees=0
c=0
while True:
  print("популяция цианобактерий:"+str(cyanobacter)+" концетрация кислорода 
  равна:"+str(c)+"%")
  time.sleep(1)
  cyanobacter+=1
  c+=10

if 100<=c:
print('наступает новая эра и новая глава в истории Земли')
print('появляются первые растения')
cyanobacter.stop
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 5):

А из цикла вы планируете выходить?)

```
import sys
import time
#import random
#from random import randint

cyanobacter= 0
trees=0
c=0

while c < 100:
  print("популяция цианобактерий:"+str(cyanobacter)+" концентрация кислорода 
  равна:"+str(c)+"%")
  time.sleep(1)
  cyanobacter+=1
  c+=10

print('наступает новая эра и новая глава в истории Земли')
print('появляются первые растения')
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import sys

cyanobacter= 0
trees=0
c=0
while True:
  print("популяция цианобактерий:"+str(cyanobacter)+" концетрация кислородаравна:"+str(c)+"%")
  time.sleep(1)
  cyanobacter+=1
  c+=10
  if 100<=c:
    print('наступает новая эра и новая глава в истории Земли')
    print('появляются первые растения')
    break
sys.exit()
```